# import external js file in meteor project

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a meteor project where I want to include the [conversational form framework](https://github.com/space10-community/conversational-form).

There is a npm package, however it is not properly imported (probably due to some kind of [bug](https://github.com/space10-community/conversational-form/issues/218)). According to the github issue, this:

```
import cf from 'conversational-form'
```

does not work, because the export function exports `cf.ConversationalForm`, not `cf` (but cf is needed for existing declarations). The form is created and styled, but cannot be addressed in the js.

I was already able to use the framework in a normal html/js/css project, so now I wanted to just include the external script as a workaround. 
However, downloading + importing in client/main.js did not work for me.

I've tried:

```
import '/imports/api/conversational-form.min.js
```

as well as:

```
$.getScript
```

in Meteor.startup.

Do I need to write specific exports in the external .js? I'm far from a professional, so I'm a little hesitant to dissect the external .js.

Any tips on how to simply mimic the html-script-inclusion? Or other ideas on how to get the framework running?

Sincerely, desperate.

Comment: Why is import '/imports/api/conversational-form.min.js not working?

Comment: no idea, I was guessing that maybe I need to `import { x } from ...` but without knowing which x I would have to import/export...

Comment: You can always import with an alias `import * as yourvar`.

Comment: I have a weird combination of errors: I tried using `import * as cf from ...` (as far as I could see, the alias didn't have any impact, was the same before); when only using this, no form is created (I can't see any dialogue), but version and options of the form are printed out. 
However when using $.getScript (which uses a URL), I get the chat dialogue, but also "cf not defined" errors. Addressing the form (e.g. event handlers) still doesn't work.

any ideas on this weird combination?

Comment: There are probably several (and better libraries) that are being maintained. My suggestion would be : try another one that is not that buggy :D

Comment: Check this out : https://www.producthunt.com/alternatives/conversational-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downloading the script, modifying it to set my options and including it via `\imports`.

VERY hacky solution, but well, it works...

Comment: It may have been better to fork the original NPM package's repo, modify the export, then include that in your project via `meteor npm install <edited-package>`. Seems like it would take just as much work as manually copying, then editing the script, but this solution would make it easier to update. It also makes it possible for other devs to trace the package back to its origins.

Answer (score 0):

Well Meteor allows you many ways to do that, the first ideas that come to my mind are:

1. Depending on your project structure you can create your own meteor package as a wrapper and internally load the library.
2. Hardcoding the script tag in you  entry point.(Im not sure if this would work to be honest but you can try).

Answer (score 0):

Meteor allow you to load external library and scope them in all the client
via the `/compatibility` folder.

Just put the file in there, and it will be scoped automaticaly.